# How to resolve a Compile error: Expected: end of statement caused by " ("

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a custom formula for the following:

to take Name, Affiliation, and Email in separate cells and combine them in a new cell as Name (Affiliation) .

I am able to do this straight into a new cell using the formula

```
=A2& " ("& B2&") " & "<"&C2&">"
```

where A2, B2, and C2 are the cells containing Name, Affiliation, and Email respectively.

But instead of copy-and-pasting this formula every time, I am trying to create a custom formula as a short cut.  However, when I try and use this same formula in VBA to create a new module like this:

```
Function Combined (name, affiliation, email)
 Combined = name&" ("&affiliation&") "&"<"&email&">"
```

the program highlights the " (" and it gives me the following error:

> Compile error:
> Expected: end of statement

If I could do a range like A2:C2 rather than A2,B2,C2, for the same effect, that would be even better!

Answer (score 8):

**Short version**

Add spaces between operators and their operands. Problem solved.

---

**Long version**

Any identifier that is immediately followed by a `&`, like `name&` and `affiliation&`, is interpreted as a `Long` variable, so the lack of whitespace in front of what's meant to be concatenation operators is causing a parse error, because VBA doesn't know what literal expression could possibly follow the `Combined = name&` assignment - the instruction is complete as it is; the only token that *should* be where `" ("` is, is an *end-of-statement* token:

> *Expected: end of statement*

Says exactly that. Everything before `" ("` is a perfectly valid instruction, except it's not terminated.

So it's not the `" ("`, it's the type hints. Insert spaces to separate the operators from the operands, and you'll fix the problem. More explicitness couldn't hurt, either:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Combined(ByVal name As String, ByVal affiliation As String, email As String) As String
    Combined = name & " (" & affiliation & ") " & "<" & email & ">"
End Function
```

When a type isn't specified, a declaration is implicitly `Variant`, which incurs some unnecessary run-time overhead.

When `ByVal` isn't specified, parameters are passed `ByRef` by default, which means the function could be assigning to the parameters.

You could also implement the function like so:

```
Combined = Join(Array(name, "(" & affiliation & ")", "<" & email & ">"), " ")
```

Comment: Or use `Join$` and get a free type hint, while stocks last. Actually, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a `Range` to your function you could do:

```
Public Function Combined(rng As Range) As Variant
    If rng.Cells.Count <> 3 Or rng.Areas.Count <> 1 Then
        Combined = cvErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        Combined = rng.Cells(1).Value & _
                   " (" & rng.Cells(2).Value & ")" & _ 
                   " <" & rng.Cells(3).Value & ">"
    End If
End Function
```

If placed in a standard code module, that function can then be invoked from Excel as, for instance, `=Combined(A2:C2)`