# VBA how to open/save/close file with extension from one folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a VBA script in which i need to go to one folder and open file with specific extension (txt) and save without making any changes and then close the file.

It should loop in the folder and open,save ,close all the file with txt extension.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "U:\test"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) ="txt" Then
        colFiles.Activate
        colFiles.save
        colFiles.closedoc
    End If
Next
```

Please help

Comment: Please provide the Issue you are facing? specify your problem..

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Gentle reminder that StackOverflow isn't a code writing service).
If you replace UCase with LCase, you have taken a big step forward

Comment: Thanks for reply @arunv - am getting below error when i run this : - "runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objFSO.GetFolder" .

Comment: try by adding reference through Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime  and try execute

Comment: I can't replicate. Is scrrun32.dll registered on the machine you're running this on?

Comment: The line `UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) ="txt"` will never be true as `UCase` means **Upper Case**. Also the lines  `colFiles.Acvtivate`etc do not make sense. `colFiles` is a collection of files which you run through and do not support any of the methods you wrote in the code.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question you need of this code:

```
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = "U:\test" //path

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt") //get all file with extension .txt

Do While MyFile <> "" 
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile  //open file *.txt
Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=True //close file and save 
MyFile = Dir //next file *.txt
Loop
```

I tried this code and works fine.

Hope this help you.

EDIT post:
try this one, copy and paste only, in your macro module

```
Sub controlFile()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = "U:\test" 'path

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt") 'get all file with extension .txt

Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile  'open file *.txt
Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=True 'close file and save
MyFile = Dir 'next file *.txt
Loop

End Sub
```

Keep me updated..(i used office 2013 and 2007 on owindows 10 and macro works fine).I don't obtain anything error.
When execute macro use f8 button to execute one code row  at time

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I tried this code and am getting error message " Compilation error : Expected end of statement .

Comment: I found this post that talk about of tour errore... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647372/vba-exel-compile-error-expected-end-of-statement-caused-by control again the code... I wait :)

Comment: Still getting compilation error . My actual extension is .qvw (Qlikview) .

Comment: i found this link that talk about how to open qvw file in excel https://community.qlikview.com/thread/72317

Comment: Thank you very much @Ferdinando for active reply. Letr me give you recap of my stituation. So i have couple of .qvw extension file in folder with some other log and txt extension files in same folder. I want to go to that XYZ folder and open only .qvw files, save them without making any changes and then close the file. Repeat the loop untill all the .qvw files are open save and closed.

Comment: You are welcome. You can read this link https://community.qlikview.com/thread/41215  where you can open with excel vba the desktop application to open qvw file save and close it....keep me update